# Prevent repetition code in methods get and post in django class vase view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

There are several lines of code in the get method that are also used in the post method. How can I prevent code repetition in this view?

```
class ProductDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = Product.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        related_products = products.tags.similar_objects()[:4]
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_reply=False, product_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        change = Chart.objects.filter(product_id=self.kwargs['pk'])

        context = (
            {'products': products, 'related_products': related_products, 'comments': comments, 
             'change': change})
        return render(request, 'home/details.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = Product.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        related_products = products.tags.similar_objects()[:4]
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_reply=False, product_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        change = Chart.objects.filter(product_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        
        context = ({'products': products, 'related_products': related_products, 'comments': comments, 
                    'change': change})
        return render(request, 'home/details.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work ?

```py
class ProductDetail(View):
    def dostuff(id):
        self.products = Product.objects.get(id)
        self.related_products = self.products.tags.similar_objects()[:4]
        self.comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_reply=False, product_id=id)
        self.change = Chart.objects.filter(product_id=id)        

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        dostuff(self.kwargs['pk'])
        context = (
            {'products': self.products, 'related_products': self.related_products, 'comments': self.comments, 
             'change': self.change})
        return render(request, 'home/details.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        dostuff(self.kwargs['pk'])
        context = ({'products': self.products, 'related_products': self.related_products, 'comments': self.comments, 
                    'change': self.change})
        return render(request, 'home/details.html', context)
```

Comment: why you don't use DetailView? It is better.

Comment: DetailView is indeed way better when handling context. I just responded to author's simple question without trying to modify his model.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use DetailView from DGCBV.

```
class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'home/details.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = context['products'] = context['product']
        context['related_products'] = obj.tags.similar_objects()[:4]
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(is_reply=False, produc=obj)
        context['change'] = Chart.objects.filter(product=obj)
        return context
```

if you rename you template to product_detail.html, you can remove template name attribute.

By the way: if you have only single product, why you named it "products" ?